# Best way to convert the content of an image into a list of polygons?

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, polygon

I have a collection of images and each image contains a set of shapes. In my application, I need these shapes as polygons (e.g. a collection of points that make up the polygons). Best way to describe my use case: Imagine a contour map of an area and I want to have these contour lines as polygons.

What is the best way to extract the shapes from the images as polygon list?

This does not need to be at run-time. I can use any tool (online or offline), script or programming language as long as I get the polygons in some format I can read in my application.

Comment: just save the points you used to draw those polygons.